# log_bin_trust_function_creators deterministic always throws an error on server restart

Tags: mysql, php, determinism

Everytime my rackspace server restarts because of some maintenance or an outage, all of my mysql functions stop working due to this deterministic error.

To fix this, I have to manually pull up the database and run `SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;`

is there anyway to have this set by default so my sql calls don't break on restart?

Comment: Either fix your functions (add the proper keywords to the definition) or fix your config - add `log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1` to `my.cnf` under the `[mysqld]` section.

Comment: @jkavalik if you post that as the answer, i'll mark it. Thanks so much!